# Terraform in Azure DevOps using betr-io/mssql_user, init keeps failing

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines

I would like to use the betr-io/mssql into my Terraform environment which is on Azure DevOps.

This is my providers.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "main"
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.providers_azurerm["main"].subscription_id

  features {
    key_vault {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
      recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults = true
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.providers_azurerm["subscription"].subscription_id
  
  features {
    key_vault {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
      recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults = true
    }
  }
}

provider "betrio-mssql" {
  debug = "false"
}
```

This is the terraform code in the 'main.tf'

```
locals {
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
    betrio-mssql = {
      source = "betr-io/mssql"
      version = "0.2.1"
    }
  }
}
```

In the resource I'm having ...

```
resource "mssql_user" "auser" {
  provider = betrio-mssql
  
  server {
    host = var.sql_host_name
    database = var.sqldb_name
  }
  username = var.username
  password = random_password.password[0].result
  roles    = [ "db_owner" ]
}
```

But still getting this error in the Init

```
Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/betrio-mssql: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not
│ have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/betrio-mssql
│ 
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external
│ consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which
│ modules are currently depending on hashicorp/betrio-mssql, run the
│ following command:
│     terraform providers
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I couldn't find a lot of samples on this issue. So posting here, what I did find was tried but no success.
If people know better ways to create users in databases please feel free.

I know that some people say that this is not a Terraform related maintenance but this user is created for each Azure-DataFactory that we are defining? Each user gets his own schema with rights on that one and a dedicated password and Connectionstring in the Keyvault. That's why I would like to create the password from out of a Terraform script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the provider's name is `mssql` so in `main.tf` it should be

```
terraform {
...
  required_providers {
...
    mssql = {
      source = "betr-io/mssql"
    }
  }
}
```